# Tornado - Non Blocking calls which return values on GET?

Tags: python, webserver, tornado

when trying to fetch data from a tornado GET method, if we need a result to be returned, the call has to be a blocking call which returns a value to the client (if we're fetching data from some third party, the result gets all the more delayed and the call is blocked till then).

Is there a way I could return processed values to the client and still have non-blocking calls  in Tornado?

Comment: just realized that my code is using the amazon product api wrapper which uses urllib2, hence the calls are all blocking. Any alternatives. I don't want to re-write the wrapper for this reason.

Comment: is monkey patching urllib a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sushant Khurana, you could "monkey patch" urllib2. Fortunately, you don't have to do it yourself: [someone else has done it for you](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html?highlight=asyncore#monkeypatching-the-standard-library)!

Check out **eventlet**: http://eventlet.net/doc/index.html

It basically implements its own asynchronous versions of `socket`, `urllib2`, `asyncore`, etc.
Check out its documentation and [this blog post](http://teddziuba.com/2010/02/eventlet-asynchronous-io-for-g.html).

I've never used it myself, but it look promising!

Comment: sorry for the late acceptance Ibolla. I think that's probably the best solution to sum it up.

Comment: blog post link is broken